# AndroidStudio error: null value in entry: workingDir=null

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I had the build/make error

error: null value in entry: workingDir=null
when building my project in AdroidStudio

Comment: Just remove the .gradle directory in the root project directory

Comment: If your question is solved, please mark it as "closed" so that others know it's closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just remove the .gradle directory in the root project directory**